# http .success() method never called, even when web service got hit

Tags: java, angularjs

Here is my angular app.js code

```
$http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/GngWebservice/rest/GngService/FeetToInch' 
            //webservice url        
                 }).success(function(data, status) {
          $scope.status = status;
          $scope.data = data;
        }).
        error(function(data, status) {
                       console.log(data);
          $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
          $scope.status = status;
      });
```

and my rest web service (java) using jersey) method is :

```
@Path("/FeetToInch")  
      @GET  
      @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)  
      public Response getoutput() throws JSONException {  


     JSONObject json=new JSONObject();
     JSONObject HEADER=new JSONObject();
     JSONObject RESPONSE=new JSONObject();
     json.put("name", "hello");
     HEADER.put("status","200");
     RESPONSE.put("data", "hello");
     json.append("HEADER", HEADER);
     json.append("RESPONSE", RESPONSE);
     String results=""+json;
     System.out.println(results);
     return Response.status(200).entity(results).build();  
      }
```

want ot send json as a response but it always show failed
 can any body tell me how to find which error occurred

Comment: can you post the response status and message you are getting

Comment: i did't get any response........and in error method it shows data=0 and status failed

Comment: Can you check in the dev console (F12) what is the reponse status being sent

Comment: it shows 0 as a status

Comment: It seems you are stuck in [Same-Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) problem, try to configure the server and add CORS headers to accept your origin (client-side)

Comment: thanks for your answers guys.......but can anyone more elaborate what exactly i have to do